# Python convert Json string to for each

Tags: gspread

I'm reading a google spreadsheet with gspread using the sheet.get_all_records(), it outputs the following:

```
[{"name": "test 0", "name1": "test 1", "name2": "test 2", "name3": "test 3"}, {"name": "test 0", "name1": "test 1", "name2": "test 2", "name3": "test 3"}, {"name": "test 0", "name1": "test 1", "name2": "test 2", "name3": "test 3"}, {"name": "test 0", "name1": "test 1", "name2": "test 2", "name3": "test 3"}]
```

I like to treat each row separatly:

```
list_of_hashes = sheet.get_all_records()
json_obj = json.dumps(list_of_hashes)
for line in json_obj:
   print (line['name'])
   print (line['name1'])
```

i get the error

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

like it's not recognizing the Json

any idea how to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a following modification?

`json.dumps()` is used for retrieving a JSON object as a string. I think that in order to modify your script, there are following 2 patterns.

### Pattern 1:

#### From :

```
json_obj = json.dumps(list_of_hashes)
```

#### To :

```
json_obj = json.loads(json.dumps(list_of_hashes))
```

### Pattern 2:

If `sheet.get_all_records()` returns a JSON object, you can directly use the returned values to for loop as follows.

```
json_obj = sheet.get_all_records()
for line in json_obj:
   print (line['name'])
   print (line['name1'])
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.